# dotenv doesn't seem to load any env variable

Tags: node.js, express, dotenv

I'm developing the standard Node+Express web app. Everything else is working fine, but I can't make the `.env` file to populate process.env

At first, I thought it was a scope problem since my app.js, where `dotenv` is called from, is within the src subfolder and `.env` is in the root. But using node tools and confirming it with a package called `find-config`, I have the correct absolute path. I've never gotten an ENOENT for a file not found.

I tried everything, from `dotenv`'s debug thingy explained in the docs, to my own debugging, making sure everything is in place. This is my latest attempt:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const realpath = require('find-config')('.env');
console.log(dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(realpath)));
```

I've paused execution and asserted that indeed `realpath` is exactly the absolute `.env` path
And here's `.env`

```
NODE_ENV=development
NODE_HOST=localhost
NODE_PORT=8080
SESSION_SECRET=eX&frsz9M*3XqFKUrK6
```

The console.log outputs `{}`, which is consistent with every avenue I've tried: never an error, never a parsed object either. Just nothingness.

Doing this:

```
const results = JSON.stringify(dotenv.config({"path":"/100%/correct/path/.env"}));
```

It throws back `{"parsed":{}}`

I've become so *suspicious* that I downloaded, installed and run the mega Hackathon Starter repo of 29k stars, which uses the [same method](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter/blob/master/app.js#L27).

Initially, it doesn't work because the author used a relative path. With the absolute path it works.

A bit more info in case it helps:

```
/* ===========  Dotenv troubleshooting  ===========
*/

const realPath = path.join(__dirname, '../.env');
const buffer = fs.readFileSync(realPath);
const envConfig = dotenv.parse(buffer, {debug:true});
l(realPath);
l(buffer);
l(envConfig);

/* end of Dotenv troubleshooting ------------------ */
```

This logs the following:

```
> node server.js

SESSION_SECRET=blabla value when parsing line 1: NODE_ENV=development
19:06:11 info: /100%/correct/path/.env
19:06:11 info: <Buffer 4e 4f 44 45 5f 45 4e 56 3d 64 65 76 65 6c 6f 70 6d 65 6e 74 0d 4e 4f 44 45 5f 48 4f 53 54 3d 6c 6f 63 61 6c 68 6f 73 74 0d 4e 4f 44 45 5f 50 4f 52 54 ... 41 more bytes>
19:06:11 info: {}
```

And as you can tell, that buffer is indeed the file:

```
/100%/correct/path $  xxd .env
00000000: 4e4f 4445 5f45 4e56 3d64 6576 656c 6f70  NODE_ENV=develop
00000010: 6d65 6e74 0d4e 4f44 455f 484f 5354 3d6c  ment.NODE_HOST=l
```

Comment: can you check the access rights for the `.env` file? I mean i don't see a problem with the code, maybe `.env` file had a different user(maybe root) upon creating.

Comment: That was a good idea! Sadly, it has read rights to everyone (and owned by the regular user), just like the Hackathon repo where it does work. :(

Comment: What is the output of `fs.readFileSync(realpath)`? It may lead to debugging the problem.

Comment: As others have mentioned, I would verify the output of `readFileSync`. `dotenv.parse` accepts a second parameter to turn on debugging which can help you understand why your parsed object is not being populated (e.g. `dotenv.parse(buf, { debug: true })`)

Answer (score 2):

After too much time scrutinizing my code, I finally discovered the issue.

Depending on operating systems and down to files themselves (and text editors and IDEs), at the end of the line you can have a Line Feed ("LF") character (0x0A, **\n**), Carriage Return ("CR") character (0x0D, **\r**) or End of Line ("EOL") character (0x0D0A, **\r\n**).

Unfortunately, `dotenv` only understands `\n` as the end of a line. So it was a parsing issue due to the simplicity of the checking. As far as I know, however, `\n` is *kind of* the standard.

[image]

For some reason, the `.env` file was using `\r` as a line separator. So it was a quick fix:

[image]

In my case, using a JetBrains product you can configure in the settings to always use the same end of line.